# Starting timer on button click in swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

Ive created a timer in swift to move a UISlider from one end to another again and again when a button is pressed. But I'm always getting a breakpoint at the timer line, although everything should be right.

```
@IBAction func setSliderValue(_ sender: UIButton){
        mytimer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    func timerAction(){
        let Range =  slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue;
        let Increment = Range/100;
        let newval = slider.value + Increment;
        if(Increment >= slider.maximumValue)
        {
            slider.setValue(newval, animated: true)
        }
        else 
        {
            slider.setValue(0, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: "getting a breakpoint" - you mean your code is crashing with an `exc_breakpoint`?

Comment: Please post the error message you see in the Xcode console.

Comment: its crashing with this green underlining saying Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 and (lldb) in the console. But only as soon as I hit the button linked to setSliderValue.

Comment: That is not the error message, hit continue in the debug to see the actual crash message.

Comment: well, its not crashing anymore looks like it was because of a line break from Xcode.

Comment: If you are pretty sure that it is a breakpoint, you need to check from the navigator (on the left) the breakpoint navigator list, I'm facing this sometimes...

Comment: oh ok thank you haven't done that.

Comment: Did you check if your slider is  not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now with the following code, though the slider is only moving from left to right until it gets invalidated.

```
@IBAction func setSliderValue(_ sender: UIButton){
        mytimer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        /*slider.setValue(100, animated: true)
        print("The value of the slider is now \(slider.value)")
        sliderValue = Int(slider.value)*/
    }


    func timerAction(){
        let Range =  slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue;
        let Increment = Range/100;
        let newval = slider.value + Increment;
        if(Increment <= slider.maximumValue)
        {
            slider.setValue(newval, animated: true)
            print("The value of the slider is now \(slider.value)")
            sliderValue = Int(slider.value)
        }
        else if (Increment >= slider.minimumValue)
        {
            slider.setValue(newval, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The check of your function is incorrect.

```
func timerAction(){
    let range =  slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue
    let increment = range/100
    let newval = slider.value + increment
    if newval <= slider.maximumValue {
        slider.setValue(newval, animated: true)
    } else {
        slider.setValue(slider.minimumValue, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Also, in your event handler, should invalidate the timer (if it's not nil) first before instancing a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps if someone else needs help on a task "starting a count down timer on a button click".

Timer itself has to be declared **inside** of the button code and additionally create a Obj-C function to update the timer that will be connected trough the #selector.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myTimer = Timer()
    var secondsToCount = 100
    
     @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
            myTimer.invalidate() 
            myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
        
        @objc func updateTimer() {
            secondsToCount -= 1
            timerDisplayed.text = String(secondsToCount)
        }
}
```

**timerDisplayed** is a label that I connected to see the value of the timer on the screen of the app.

**SWIFT 5.3 & Xcode 12.0.1**